# Однородные придаточные условия

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли сказать, что здесь в обоих случаях СПП с однородными придаточными условия и запятые в скобках не нужны?

Если компания разработала стандарты на определенные марки стали (,) и при использовании данных сталей они дали трещину, коррозию или другую неисправность, кто является ответственным в этом случае?

Если вы изготовили продукцию (,) и она отвечает методам испытаний, то нет никакой проблемы в том, чтобы сослаться на этот метод испытаний (стандарт) и обозначить, что вы отвечаете его требованиям.

Answer (score 1):

Да, именно так, в обоих случаях СПП с однородными придаточными, (только  в первом не  условия, а определительными -в каком случае?) и запятые в скобках не нужны.

Условные часто похожи на сопоставительные при союзе ЕСЛИ...ТО :Придаточные сопоставительные присоединяются к главной части СПП с помощью союзов в то время как, между тем как, если... то, тогда как: Если раньше мне били в морду, то теперь вся в крови душа (Ес); На фронтоне всегда сидели сытые голуби, между тем как тысячи воробьев дождём пересыпались с крыши на крышу (Б.); Слово "страсть" заключает в себе понятие более чувственное, тогда как слово "пафос" заключает в себе понятие более нравственное (Бел.).
Части такого СПП семантически равноправны, придаточное отличается лишь союзом; грамматические отношения близки к сочинительным, выражаемым с помощью союзов а, же. Сопоставляются предметы по их признакам (страсть - чувственное, пафос - нравственное; голуби сидели, воробьи пересыпались), сопоставление опирается на антонимические отношения (раньше - теперь).
Союз если... то нужно рассматривать как омоним условного если (то), причем в сопоставительном союзе то является обязательным элементом, а в условном - факультативным соотносительным словом.

Comment: Спасибо большое. А что значит "сопоставительными"?

Comment: Прошу прощения, поторопилась, это именно условия, ТО можно опустить. Сейчас изменю в ответе и поясню

Comment: Спасибо. Я все равно об их существовании узнала только сейчас. Не помню, чтобы в школе мы на этом подробно акцентировали внимание.

Answer (score 1):

> Если вы изготовили продукцию (,) и она отвечает методам испытаний, то
>   нет никакой проблемы в том...

Запятая в скобках **не нужна**.

> Если компания разработала стандарты на определенные марки (,) стали и
>   при использовании данных сталей они дали трещину, коррозию или другую
>   неисправность, кто является ответственным в этом случае?

Запятая в скобках **не нужна**, т. к. разбивает словосочетание "марки стали". Но предложение коряво, требует доработки. Ведь ***трещину***-то или ***другую неисправность*** *дали* не сами марки стали, а какие-то конструкции, изготовленные из этих сталей.

Comment: Просто не туда поставила скобки. Исправила.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл обоих предложений неясен или выражен очень неудачно, грамматика также оставляет желать лучшего, фактически переделывать их надо полностью.

Что касается вида придаточных, то это **ОДНОРОДНЫЕ придаточные УСЛОВИЯ** (запятая не ставится). В них можно использовать сложные союзы В ТОМ СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ, и тогда не будет никаких сомнений в том, что они относятся к условным придаточным.

**Вариант исправленных предложений**

(1) Если компания разработала стандарты на условия применения определенных марок стали  и при использовании стальных конструкций  в соответствии с этими стандартами они дали трещину, коррозию или другую неисправность, кто является ответственным в этом случае?

(2) Если вы изготовили продукцию  и она прошла испытания  по методу, указанному в технических условиях на эту продукцию,  то нет никакой проблемы в том, чтобы сослаться на этот метод испытаний (стандарт) и подтвердить соответствие продукции стандартным требованиям.